# parsing argument/parameter from commandline

Tags: c#

i edited my code to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Search
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string abc = string.Format("{0}", args[0]);
            string latestversion = string.Format("{1}", args[1]);
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "sslist.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.net" + type;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.Start();
            string procOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string procError = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            TextWriter outputlog = new StreamWriter("C:\\Work\\listofsnapshot.txt");
            outputlog.Write(procOutput);
            outputlog.Close();
            string greatestVersionNumber = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Work\\listofsnapshot.txt")) 
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                    var line = sr.ReadLine();
                    var versionNumber = line.Replace(latestversion, "");
                    if(versionNumber.Length != line.Length)
                    greatestVersionNumber = versionNumber;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(greatestVersionNumber);

            TextWriter latest = new StreamWriter("C:\\Work\\latestbuild.properties");
            latest.Write("Version_Number=" + greatestVersionNumber);
            latest.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

where `string type` and `string latest version` are the arguments parsed.

So, my commandline looks like this:

```
c:/searchversion.exe "/SASE Lab Tools" "6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_RELEASE_"
```

where `"/SASE Lab Tools"` should be stored as a string `abc` and `"6.70_Extensions/6.70.102/ANT_RELEASE_"` should be stored as a string as `latestversion`.

However i get an error: System.Format.Exception: Index(zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list at line 14:

```
string latestversion = string.Format("{1}", args[1]);
```

Anybody knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for

```
string latestversion = string.Format("{1}", args[1]);
```

You specified the 2nd item in the array of the string format, for which there isnt one. So the array is out of bounds.  you meant

```
string latestversion = string.Format("{0}", args[1]);
```

Comment: :) no worries, its an easy one to do, when doing the cut/paste change 0's to 1.. oh not that one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string latestversion = string.Format("{0}", args[0]);
```

**updated**

if you go debugging do you have your args[] filled with data?

Answer (score 0):

See `abc` and `latestversion` are two different strings. And since you are formatting those one-by-one, you need to start your format specifiers by 0 each time. So, your code should be:

```
string latestversion = string.Format("{0}", args[1]);
```